# Preventing gcc from inlining all functions

Tags: c, gcc, inline

The following code prevents GCC compiler inline a specific function.

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) my_func() 
{
  ... 
}
```

I wish to prevent gcc from inlining all functions.
Can I do it without adding the attribute to all functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The global option to avoid inlining (when using `-O2` or other optimisation flags) is `-fno-inline`

> -fno-inline
>       Do not expand any functions inline apart from those marked with the always_inline attribute. **This is the default when not optimizing.**

(source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

If you're doing this to reduce code size, I suggest that you throw in the `-Os` option (optimize for size)